# Is the improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^xf(\lambda)d\lambda + C$ equal to the undefinite integral $\int f(\lambda)d\lambda$?

Tags: calculus

Background:
The fundamental theorem of Calculus says
$$ \int_b^a f(x) dx = F(a) - F(b) \,\,\,\,\, \text{where $f(x)$ is the derivative of $F(x)$} $$
I conjecture that $F(x)$ is like the area under the curve from the limit $-\infty$ to $x$, hence $F(a) - F(b)$ is like take the area under the curve from the limit $-\infty$ to $a$ and subtract to is the area under the curve from the limit $-\infty$ to $b$, so get the area under the curve from $b$ to $a$.

*Q*: Is the improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^xf(\lambda)d\lambda + C$ equal to the undefinited integral $\int f(\lambda)d\lambda$ (Edit: please complete proof)?

Comment: The "improper integral" is not even convergent. In the FTC, you don't have information of $f$ outside $(a,b)$. Why $-\infty$?

Comment: Wait.. you cannot treat $x$ as constant and variable at the same time. (It was assumed as constant in the bounds of integral and variable of integration). You can consider them in separate cases.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{-\infty}^xf(y)\,dy=\int_{-\infty}^0f(y)\,dy+\int_0^xf(y)\,dy=C+\int f(x)\,dx$$
Then this integral and constant can be merged into one as a property of indefinite integrals

Comment: Please complete proof.

Comment: this isn't homework club

Comment: perfect because is no homework